# how to add jar file in the latest apache netbeans 11.2 linux?

Tags: linux, netbeans, linux-mint

How to add jar/file to add mysql connector .IMPORTANT : I am using the new apache netbeans version 11.2 and there is no Library, only Source Packages , Test Packages , Java Dependencies and Project Files.

Comment: It looks like you have a Maven project so there won't be a _Libraries_ node for your project in the _Projects_ panel. That is nothing to do with the version of NetBeans you are using; it has always been that way for Maven projects. To add the **Connector/J** jar file to your project, specify it as a `<dependency>` in **pom.xml**. See [Installing Connector/J Using Maven](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-maven.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you very much sir ,you saved me alot of time